# Why is total_items larger than curr_items in Memcached when I have plenty of memory and items are set to never expire?

Tags: memcached

I have a memcached instance set up with 10GB of space on an ec2 instance with plenty of memory (15 gb I believe). I'm confused to see that the stat "total_items" is larger than the curr_items stat considering that when items are written to memcache, the timeout is set to 0 (never expire). Could someone explain these stats for me and why it does not seem to have every item in the cache still?

`STAT cmd_set 174978
...
STAT delete_misses 0
STAT delete_hits 0
...
STAT bytes_read 45749254
STAT bytes_written 26472821
STAT limit_maxbytes 10737418240
...
STAT bytes 25386981
STAT curr_items 99198
STAT total_items 174978
STAT evictions 0
STAT reclaimed 0`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think `total_items` means what you think it means. It is a simple counter which increases whenever something is stored. A simple test verifies this. Store the same object twice. `curr_items` will be one, `total_items` will be two. Since your evictions and reclaims are both zero, everything that was ever stored is still there, as nothing has been evicted and no expired keys have been reclaimed. The data may have changed over time, but everything is still there.

Comment: Thanks, I hope that's the case. I think I should be able to test that.

Comment: I am new to memcached and want to use it with Magento. Magento by default support the memcached. So after enabling memcached, curr_items is increasing whenever i go to different pages. But, when I reload the same page then total_items is not increasing. Can u pls share the exact meaning of total_items? Is this not increases whenever reload the same page?

Comment: Ok, you should probably ask this as a new question, rather than add it as a comment. But here goes anyway. From what I understand Magento only uses memcached to store session data (which is otherwise stored on the FS). I suspect that the reason you are not seeing total_items increase is because Magento only adds session data to memcached, if it does not already exist, but I'm not really that sure of the internal workings of Magento.